# how to insert into a list with in a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have list as shown named testing.

```
testing=['how','are','you',['how','is','life','going',['hope','you','are','doing']]].
```

how to insert into the second list within the list as shown here

```
['hope','you','doing','great']
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you want to insert into a list within a list within a list but the real secret, as @rje points out in his answer, is knowing how to address the list you want to change. Once you have an expression that does that you just operate on it like any other list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get to the second list by index: `testing[3][4]`. so for example

```
testing[3][4].insert(0,'hello')
```

`testing[3]` is the first embedded list. To get the 4th item of that you do `testing[3][4]`.